# C# Populating list box

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, populate, inventory-management

Im having trouble populating my listbox. I initially got help from someone on the site but doesn't seem to have worked fully. I'm trying to populate a listbox with items from a textfile here's the code so far:

```
namespace ACW2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for InventoryWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    ///

    public partial class InventoryWindow : Window
    {
        public InventoryWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            categoryComboBox.Items.Add("All");
            categoryComboBox.Items.Add("Pizza");
            categoryComboBox.Items.Add("Burger");
            categoryComboBox.Items.Add("Sundry");
            categoryComboBox.SelectedValue = "All";

            PopulateList();
        }

        private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void categoryComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            PopulateList();
        }

        public void PopulateList()
        {
            listBox.Items.Clear();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"inventory.txt"))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
                    {
                        string StringListItem = sr.ReadLine();
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(StringListItem) &&
                           (categoryComboBox.SelectedItem != null &&
                           (StringListItem.Contains(categoryComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()))))
                        listBox.Items.Add(StringListItem);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    }
```

It just ends up with an empty listbox. However, this code does populates the listbox but there's two StreamReaders I feel as if that's redundant:

```
namespace ACW2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for InventoryWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    ///

    public partial class InventoryWindow : Window
    {
        public InventoryWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            categoryComboBox.Items.Add("All");
            categoryComboBox.Items.Add("Pizza");
            categoryComboBox.Items.Add("Burger");
            categoryComboBox.Items.Add("Sundry");
            categoryComboBox.SelectedValue = "All";
        }

        private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void categoryComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox.Items.Clear();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("inventory.txt");
            string i = sr.ReadToEnd();
            string[] n = i.Split('\n');
            foreach (string s in n)
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(s);
            }
        }



        public void PopulateList()
        {
            listBox.Items.Clear();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"inventory.txt"))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
                    {
                        string StringListItem = sr.ReadLine();
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(StringListItem) &&
                           (categoryComboBox.SelectedItem != null &&
                           (StringListItem.Contains(categoryComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()))))
                            listBox.Items.Add(StringListItem);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the format of the inventory file?

Comment: Why the `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"inventory.txt"))` syntax? Couldn't you use `StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"inventory.txt");` without the `{}` ?

Comment: Gusman it is just a list:
pizza, beef, 0.50, 500
pizza, chicken, 0.50, 500
pizza, dough, 0.50, 1500
pizza, mushrooms, 0.25, 500
pizza, olives, 0.35, 500
burger, beef-Patty, 0.66, 500
burger, bun, 0.25, 500
burger, cheddar, 0.55, 500
sundry, baked-beans, 0.35, 500
sundry, chips, 0.33, 500

Comment: I think first and foremost I'd populate all the lists on the Loaded events of the respective listbox. That way you 100% for sure know the list box is ready for you to work with.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var line = File.ReadAllLines(@"inventory.txt"))
{
    listBox.Items.Add(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that from code-behind, I would set up a ViewModel with an ObservableCollection of your item types (eg. string or something a bit more robust) and bind the ComboBox from XAML to that collection property name.

That way you will have an easier time maintaining this application + view separation comes for free :)

```html
// SampleViewModel.cs
public ObservableCollection<string> Categories = new ObservableCollection<string>();

// SampleView.xaml
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:SampleViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<ListView ItemSource="{Binding Categories}" />
```

This should do it :)